# Calculation form, behind the comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

This calculation script works almost, but it doesn't do anything with a value with a number behind the comma. Can anyone help me?

```
var selects = $('select');
var inputs = $('input');
selects.change(calculate);
inputs.keyup(calculate);

function calculate()
{
    var runningTotal = 0;
    selects.each(function(i)
    {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val());
        var qty = inputs.eq(i).val();
        runningTotal += (val*qty);
    });

    $('#grandtotal').val(runningTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert a string to a number with a decimal point, don't use `parseInt()`, but `parseFloat()` instead.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/mjs32/1/

```
alert(parseInt('10.10'));
alert(parseFloat('10,10'));
alert(parseFloat('10.10'));
```

You need to convert you commas to '.'s apparantely for the parseFloat() to work.

```
parseFloat(('10,10').replace(",", "."));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selects.each(function(i)
    {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val());

       if (val.indexOf('"') != -1) {
            val = val.replace(/"/g, '');
        }

        var qty = inputs.eq(i).val();
        runningTotal += (val*qty);
    });
```